# TLS library problem when connecting to Dovecot

Tags: tls, certificates, email

I have a Comodo PositiveSSL certificate issued for `mail.btcontract.com` and I've set up Postfix and Dovecot to work with it in the following way:

Postfix main.cf:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file  = /etc/ssl/mail/mail_btcontract_com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file   = /etc/ssl/mail/mail_btcontract_com.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile     = /etc/ssl/mail/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
smtp_tls_CAfile      = /etc/ssl/mail/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
```

dovecot.conf:

```
ssl_cert =< /etc/ssl/mail/mail_btcontract_com.pem
ssl_key  =< /etc/ssl/mail/mail_btcontract_com.key
```

I've generated `pem` out of `crt` following this tutorial: http://blog.wong42.com/2011/05/converting-a-ssl-certificate-from-crt-format-to-pem/

The problem is that when I try to connect to my server from a Thunderbird mail client I see the following errors:

[image]
[image]

At the same time in `/var/log/mail.log` I see this:

```
Nov 16 12:15:57 BTContractTest postfix/smtpd[22870]: connect from 51-28-134-95.pool.ukrtel.net[95.134.28.51]
Nov 16 12:15:58 BTContractTest postfix/smtpd[22870]: Anonymous TLS connection established from 51-28-134-95.pool.ukrtel.net[95.134.28.51]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Nov 16 12:15:58 BTContractTest postfix/smtpd[22870]: warning: TLS library problem: 22870:error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:s3_pkt.c:1258:SSL alert number 48:
Nov 16 12:15:58 BTContractTest postfix/smtpd[22870]: lost connection after STARTTLS from 51-28-134-95.pool.ukrtel.net[95.134.28.51]
```

When I try `openssl s_client -connect mail.btcontract.com:143 -starttls imap` I first see this:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = mail.btcontract.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = mail.btcontract.com
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = mail.btcontract.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

What is going on and what should I do fix all this?
Also, these are all the files I've got from certificate authority:
[image]

I don't use intermediate certs anywhere, could that be the source of problem?

**UPDATE**

Following Thomas Pornin's advice I did the following:

```
cat mail_btcontract_com.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt > full.crt
```

and then in Postfix main.cf:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file  = /etc/ssl/mail/full.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file   = /etc/ssl/mail/mail_btcontract_com.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile     = /etc/ssl/mail/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
smtp_tls_CAfile      = /etc/ssl/mail/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
```

dovecot.conf:

```
ssl_cert =< /etc/ssl/mail/full.crt
```

And now I'm getting a different error:

```
Nov 16 13:28:09 BTContractTest postfix/smtpd[23921]: warning: cannot get RSA private key from file /etc/ssl/mail/mail_btcontract_com.key: disabling TLS support 
Nov 16 13:28:09 BTContractTest postfix/smtpd[23921]: warning: TLS library problem: 23921:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:330:
```

I've tried switching places of concatenated certificates and also tried to inclue root ca like this:

```
cat AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt mail_btcontract_com.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt > full.crt
```

But no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSL/TLS, the server is supposed to send not only its certificate, but a complete chain that goes from the root to the server's certificate (the root itself may be omitted, but the intermediate CA should be sent). If the server does not send a complete chain, then it is up to the client to try to complete it, e.g. by downloading the missing certificate, but it is not mandatory for SSL/TLS clients to do any effort in that respect. A client may reject an incomplete chain right away.

The `smtpd_tls_cert_file` option should point to a file that contains the chain, i.e. all the certificates in PEM format, concatenated in the chain order (starting with the server's certificate). See [the documentation](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html#server_tls). PEM format is the one where the certificate is encoded in Base64, with an explicit `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` header. If you have a certificate in binary format, you can convert it to PEM with:

```
openssl x509 -inform DER -in cert.crt -out cert.pem
```

First open with a text editor (or a simple `more` command) the certificates you have to see if they are in binary, or already in PEM. Then concatenates the PEM certificates in a single text file, as described by the Postfix documentation.

Comment: Root and two intermediary certs appear to be in text format so I've concatenated them in single file and pointed Postfix and Dovecot to it. Now I see the different error in `mail.log` when I try to connect: `Nov 16 13:28:09 BTContractTest postfix/smtpd[23921]: warning: cannot get RSA private key from file /etc/ssl/mail/mail_btcontract_com.key: disabling TLS support
Nov 16 13:28:09 BTContractTest postfix/smtpd[23921]: warning: TLS library problem: 23921:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:x509_cmp.c:330:
`

Comment: And `openssl` command response is: `3073783484:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:`

Comment: Chances are that you concatenated the certificates in the wrong order. Postfix will use the _first_ certificate in the file as its own certificate, and will try to match the private key with the public key in that certificate.

Comment: I've tried them in all combinations always having `mail_btcontract_com.crt` first and then two intermediate certs after it. So three certs in total... Perhaps I should include Root CA as first and then the three remaining CA's?

Comment: After concatenating three certs and issuing `openssl s_client -connect mail.btcontract.com:143 -starttls imap -CApath /etc/ssl/mail/` (with explicit path to root CA directory) the output is fine. I don't yet understand why Postfix still has problems.

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar problem with Postfix and Dovecot on Ubuntu. I had purchased the basic SSL certificate from Comodo and because I selected "other" as the server type I ended up with a zip file with four certificate files in it, as per the above posts.

I wasn't getting security exceptions in the client. In my case I couldn't even get past the account setup and server detection in Thunderbird, despite selecting the correct ports in Thunderbird. In the server's system log I was getting SSL connection abort errors about unknown CA, much like mentioned above.

I fixed this successfully by using a text editor to concatenate all four certificates into one file, starting with my own cert at the top and then subsequently the two intermediate certs and finally the CA cert at the bottom. I then pointed the config of both Postfix and Dovecot to this combined file and Thunderbird was able to connect and I could send/receive email.

Comment: This is effectively the answer Thomas provided.

Answer (score 3):

Verify that your Key is not protected by passphrase.
Postfix does not supports passphrase protected Keys
anyway you can remove the passphrase from the key using an openssl command

```
openssl rsa -in passphrase.key -out nopassphrase.key
```

is not necessary to include the Root CA
if your CA Bundle does not include your CA Root
you can append it:

```
cat /etc/ssl/mail/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

And then change this line:

> smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/mail/AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt

for this one

```
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved the problem a week ago or so.

Comment: I come from this tutorial from DigitalOcean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot) which doesn't include the `smtpd_tls_CAfile` directive at all, as soon as I used it (without using any of the above from this answer) it started working